# RedirectMatch: Remove question mark

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm redirecting an old website to a new URL using `RedirectMatch`. (I don't need to preserve the original query string, hence the "?" at the end).

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/cms/index.php$ http://www.mysite.com?`

The redirect works, however I'm left with an ugly question mark at the end URL after being redirected:

`www.mysite.com?`

Is there any way to remove it?

Edit: I'm throwing in the .htacces file I'm using at the moment:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cms/index.php$ http://www.mysite.com?

# BEGIN WPSuperCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/index.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/index.html.gz" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>

# END WPSuperCache

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]




# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**EDIT**: In the end I got it working using anubhava suggestion. BUT I had to make a separate `.htaccess` file in the `/cms` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use mod_rewrite using code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^cms/index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I tried pasting your code, but it does not redirect me anywhere. (yes, it's on line 1 of my .htaccess). For some reason, only `redirectmatch` seems to work for me...

Comment: Make sure to enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is definetely enabled, as I am using wordpress on the same domain - also there are several other (wordpress-related) rewrite-rules in my .htaccess file. I'm posting my .htacces so you can take a look...

Comment: Clear your browser cache then restart your browser and insert my suggested RewriteRule just below `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested, still no luck. The only thing that seems to work is my approach on line 1.

Comment: I'm glad that you got it working eventually. Voted up your question because you have provided all the details needed to solve your problem.